# Split country code from the Phone number using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, components, etl

Im creating a SSIS package to check if the existing phone numbers country codes are matching with the its country.For that i need to split country code from the phone number and is there a way to split using any component is SSIS?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using SQL (if reading from database) using LEFT() or SUBSTRING() functions, as example if the first three characters are the country code you can use:

```
SELECT LEFT([PhoneNumber],3) FROM Table
```

More info at:

- [LEFT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Within SSIS, you can achieve this using Derived column component, for the example aboveyou can use:

```
LEFT([PhoneNumber],3)
```

- [SSIS Derived Columns with Multiple Expressions vs Multiple Transformations](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-derived-columns-with-multiple-expressions-vs-multiple-transformations/)
- [Derived Column Transformation in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/derived-column-transformation-in-ssis/)
- [Derived Column Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks.But the thing is some Phone numbers do not have country codes.So getting first 03 characters may not correct.

Comment: @Mishi this is just an example, you have to provide more details in your question to get more help